# Firebase : Filters on Cohorts

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I cannot find any way to apply filters on Cohorts shown on Firebase console. I need filters for variety of reasons like User retention for a particular app version or app language, etc. So, is there any way to achieve these results through the Firebase console. I know that this can be achieved in BigQuery but it would be super convenient if the filter could be applied on the console itself.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We are currently looking into adding support for Filtered Cohorts in Firebase Analytics. I agree that this would be a very valuable feature.

Comment: Is there a planned release date for this feature or an alternative way to implement this feature using bigquery?

Comment: I can't announce a release date, but it is possible in BigQuery.  We are working on a sample query to show you how to do this.

Comment: @steve-ganem hi Steve. 5 month ahead. Is there are query example available for cohorts aggregations from BQ?

Comment: @SteveGanem Hi Steve! Could you share some more informations about Filtered Cohorts? Or at least provide some example query to fetch that data from BigQuery?

Comment: @SteveGanem I also second this request. It would be great if you could do a tutorial with Felipe Hoffa (BigQuery) on this topic.

Comment: It's 2018 and the filter is still "not applicable". Do you you have a plan to add this feature in the future?

Comment: There's a BigQuery example for building cohorts with filters on [Firebase Help](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9037342?hl=en) (last one). But no further retention calculation.