# Firebase Cohorts in BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am trying to replicate Firebase Cohorts using BigQuery. I tried the query from this post: [Firebase exported to BigQuery: retention cohorts query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509431/firebase-exported-to-bigquery-retention-cohorts-query), but the results I get don't make much sense.

I manage to get the users for period_lag 0 similar to what I can see in Firebase, however, the rest of the numbers don't look right:

***Results:***
[image]

There is one of the period_lag missing (only see 0,1 and 3 -> no 2) and the user counts for each lag period don't look right either! I would expect to see something like that:

***Firebase Cohort:***
[image]

I'm pretty sure that the issue is in how I replaced the parameters in the original query with those from Firebase. Here are the bits that I have updated in the original query:

```
#standardSQL
WITH activities AS (
  SELECT answers.user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS id,
    FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m', DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(answers.user_dim.first_open_timestamp_micros))) AS period
  FROM `dataset.app_events_*` AS answers
  JOIN `dataset.app_events_*` AS questions
  ON questions.user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id = answers.user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id
 -- WHERE CONCAT('|', questions.tags, '|') LIKE '%|google-bigquery|%' 

(...)

WHERE cohorts_size.cohort >= FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m', DATE('2017-11-01'))
ORDER BY cohort, period_lag, period_label
```

So I'm using `user_dim.first_open_timestamp_micros` instead of `create_date` and `user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id` instead of `id` and `parent_id`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a misunderstanding in the concept of how and which data to retrieve into the `activities` table. Let me state the differences between the case presented in the other StackOverflow question you linked, and the case you are trying to reproduce:

- In the other question, `answers.creation_date` refers to a date value that is not fix, and can have different values for a single user. I mean, the same user can post two different answers in two different dates, that way, you will end up with two `activities` entries like: `{[ID:user1, date:2018-01],[ID:user1, date:2018-02],[ID:user2, date:2018-01]}`.
- In your question, the use of `answers.user_dim.first_open_timestamp_micros` refers to a date value that is fixed in the past, because as stated [in the documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846), that variable refers to *The time (in microseconds) at which the user first opened the app*. That value is unique, and therefore, for each user you will only have one `activities` entry, like:`{[ID:user1, date:2018-01],[ID:user2, date:2018-02],[ID:user3, date:2018-01]}`.

I think that is the reason why you are not getting information about the lagged retention of users, because you are not recording each time a user accesses the application, but only the first time they did.

Instead of using `answers.user_dim.first_open_timestamp_micros`, you should look for another value from the ones available in the documentation link I shared before, possibly `event_dim.date` or `event_dim.timestamp_micros`, although you will have to take into account that these fields refer to an *event* and not to a *user*, so you should do some pre-processing first. For testing purposes, you can use some of the [publicly available BigQuery exports for Firebase](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7030014?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512).

---

Finally, as a side note, it is pointless to *JOIN* a table with itself, so regarding your edited Standard SQL query, it should better be:

```
#standardSQL
WITH activities AS (
  SELECT answers.user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS id,
    FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m', DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(answers.user_dim.first_open_timestamp_micros))) AS period
  FROM `dataset.app_events_*` AS answers
  GROUP BY id, period
```